# DevExpress Charts for Java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, charts, devexpress

I'm using [DevExpress Web Development Charts](http://js.devexpress.com/WebDevelopment/Charts) for JavaScript charts.

I got a big surprise when I downloaded the trial for testing some basic implementation. It downloads an `.exe` file with a couple of samples implemented in .NET technology.

Well, for my project I must use Java/JSP. Is it possible to use the HTML5 charts of DevExpresswith Java? I've been looking in the downloaded files but it seems a bit complicated to extract only the js/HTML code related to the charts.

So, my question is: **is it possible to use DevExpresscharts with JSP?** If yes, where can I download the required libraries?

Comment: You can download trial with js/HTML code from [here](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/VizGallery/). Just click `Download Free Trial` button.

Comment: Hmm you are right. Weird, if you click in the "Download Free Trial" in the home page of the product, it downloads an exe.. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress Team directly?

Comment: Well because in the website it's pretty obvious where the links to download the trial are... And I thought it would faster to ask here, because certainly someone would already had the same issue.

Comment: It seems that they made all links download the .exe file. Can you please specify the direct link ?